# need help with array list

Tags: groovy

I'm having difficulty in putting 16 characters into an array list. I'm using the letters abcdefghabcdegh.

Many thanks.

Comment: post the code you have that's not working, we can't guess it

Comment: Would you please give us some more details? Maybe you can state the entire problem as you received it: that would be best.

Comment: This is not a particularly well defined question.  I am down voting because you have not made any changes to your question based on the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

does

```
"abcdefghabcdegh".toList()
```

work for your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

You provided very little information on what you are exactly trying to do, but [this guide](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections) should help you on your way.

Comment: Im creating a pelmanism game which is 4 by 4 there are 16 letters which are 8 pair, i need them in the board, so when i input the column number and row number i need to see which letter it is, i need an array list